# Still deleting referenced objects even with foreign key constraint (no action)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, constraints

I'm using entity framework 5 model first.

I have some entities in my model and most of them have one-to-many relationships with "no action" foreign key constraint on delete and update.

But I'm still able to delete father and child objects with no errors (on EF4 I used to get an exception warning that I cannot delete an object because there's another referencing it)

Part of the code generated by EF5 model first:

```
...
... Create all tables...
...
... Create all foreign key constraints ... 
...
-- Creating foreign key on [TEstTela_ID] in table 'TEstPermissao'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TEstPermissao]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TEstTelaTEstPermissao]
FOREIGN KEY ([TEstTela_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TEstTela]
    ([ID])
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
....
```

Delete Object Code:

```
...
EstContextDB CurrentContext = new EstContextDB();  // inherits from DbContext

CurrentContext.Set<TEstTela>().Remove(currentTEstTelaEntity);
CurrentContext.SaveChanges();  /* Exception should be thrown here
 because at least one TEstPermissao object references this
 currentTEstTelaEntity but it still delete the object without
 errors or exceptions, and plus the TEstPermissao object
that references this currentTEstTelaEntity gets its reference as 'null' */
```

Comment: Use `Fluent API` to set off the the Cascade Delete: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620%28v=msdn.10%29.aspx#CascadeDelete)

Comment: @Tico On EF5 I need to specify on code of Fluent API that i wont automatically cascade delete? Even with MODEL first?

Comment: I only use Code First, so I'm not the ideal source. But, even on Code First I always set both DataAnnotation and Fluent API (where applicable). Since your `SQL` is not working, try the `Fluent API`

Comment: You cannot use Fluent API with Model First.

Comment: So how to disable the OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention and ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention with Model First?

Comment: Model-First does not have any conventions you could disable. Those conventions only have a meaning with Code-First.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doesn't have to do with cascading delete. You try to delete the parent `TEstTelaEntity` and EF sets the foreign key from the child `TEstPermissao` to this parent `TEstTelaEntity` to `null` (apparently the relationship is optional) and then sends an UPDATE statement for the child and a DELETE statement for the parent to the database. If cascading delete would kick in the child would be deleted as well, not only the parent. The result is consistent and valid: You just have a `TEstPermissao` entity in the database now without any reference to a `TEstTelaEntity`.

The foreign key is set to `null` only in the case that the child is loaded and attached to the context when you delete the parent. Otherwise you would indeed get the exception about a constraint violation you are expecting. (I believe this difference between attached vs. detached children is the same in EF 4 and EF 5.)

If you really don't want to delete a parent as long as it has any children, check with appropriate code if the parent has children or not in order to decide if `Remove` should be called.

Comment: ok! Thanks, i found the issue... its because i set 0..1 to many instead of 1 to many relationship